# Is it possible to get the sum of all contiguous subarrays in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

As part of a larger problem I'm solving, I'm curious whether it's possible ***in linear time*** to go from

```
{a_0, a_1, ..., a_n-1}
```

to generating a mapping

```
f(i,j): sum of elements over range [i,j) for all i,j in {0, 1, ..., n - 1}
```

e.g.

```
{ 5, 1, 89, 0 }

----> 

f(0,1) = 5
f(0,2) = 5 + 1 = 6
f(0,3) = 5 + 1 + 89 = 95
f(0,4) = 5 + 1 + 89 + 0 = 95
f(1,2) = 1
f(1,3) = 1 + 89 = 90
f(1,4) = 1 + 89 + 0 = 90
f(2,3) = 89
f(2,4) = 89 + 0 = 89
f(3,4) = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you cannot produce an O(n<sup>2</sup>) amount of data in linear time, you can build a data structure in linear time that would let you compute each of `f(x,y)` in O(1).

For this you need to build an array `s` such that s<sub>*i*</sub> represents a sum of `a` from zero to `i`, inclusive of both ends.

You can build an array of partial sums by setting `s[0] = a[0]` and then setting `s[i] = s[i-1] + a[i]` for each `i` above zero.

Having an array of partial sums lets you compute

```
f(x,y) = s[y] - (x==0 ? 0 : s[x-1])
```

Comment: This can be done without any auxiliary  data-structure.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi It depends a great deal on what you mean by "this".